# ev3 brick blocked during running a program

Tags: ev3, mindstorms

I pressed "Run my program" (a simple one), and it is stuck with "mindstorms sound_turn_on" displayed on the screen. The name of my program is sound_turn_on. I am using LabView to program it. Now LabView can't recognize the ev3 brick, because it's blocked. What should I do? Take out the batteries and put them back? Would harm the brick in any way?

Comment: Have you tried pressing the center button and the button on the left-bottom under the screen simultaneously? That should stop your running program and could get you back to "normal" use of your EV3. If that doesn't work, removing and reinserting batteries is your best option.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work, in the end i removed the batteries and it was alright, thank you very much! :)